# Can a laser guided laser induced plasma chanel be used to transfer electricity efficiantly?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, laser

In my previous questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278646/electric-diagonal-rail-for-rockets-space-shuttle-usinng-a-modified-e-fan), on [engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/electric-turbine-engine), [aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26342/what-flies-better-in-turbulent-wind), and [space exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/can-blimps-be-chained-into-the-edge-of-space). The subject of Electric powered space flight has a wide rang of problems and I will do my best to keep it broken up and simple.
 I have asked the plausibility of using a light weight rail supported by huge blimps for an alternative way to transfer a pay load to space not orbit. I have concluded with help that the main problem is the transfer of power to the E-fan. Like the high speed mono rail that transfer is still done like and electric trolley car with the overhead wires. The turbulence that can shift the modified extra large E-fan plane over several meters would would hit the rail.

**Although this device was not designed for this propose could it transfer electricity to the plane if laser guidance was used as well?**

[image]

Picture taken in 2001 the researchers fed a three million volt current between two electrodes, which a high intensive laser beam discharges in a goal-directed and controlled way - therefore this artificial lightning is in a straight line. (file size: 1030 kb) (sourcee: Uni Jena/FU Berlin/TU Berlin, Germany)
http://www.teramobile.org/press/stp_gateway0801/stp_gateway0801.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been suggested as a way to generate artificial lightning. The purpose intended was not to efficiently transmit power for electrical applications, but rather to deposit a lot of high energy charge on a target. During the period 1984-92 there was a program called Strategic Defense Initiative (SDI), or Reagan's Star Wars program. Vestiges of this continue. An idea similar to this was proposed as a way to destroy incoming ballistic missiles. It was though a bit of an outlier in the set of schemes proposed.